# Laravel 4.2 Files to upload after Composer Update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I had a website created in Laravel 4.2, its live and had to make some changes in it. To make these changes I had to use a package that wasn't used before, so I required the package and did **composer update**.

The new package that I've used, has created a folder inside **app/config/packages**.

Besides the controllers and views where I've made the changes, what files I'll have to upload now? **Composer update** command has updated a few packages and downloaded the new one.

I just want to know whether I'll have to re-upload whole site or there are some specific files or folders that I can upload and get the website working perfectly.

Comment: can you describe what changes you need to do in your running website and what is that package name you have updated?

Comment: I would consider Capistrano for deployment. And go to a one click deploy plan. Capistrano will take your latest release from your repository and deploys it. After the deploy has happened a composer update should be enough.

Comment: @DavidMaes This website was done months ago and I had to upload it on client's server which he had been using for his other websites. Anyways, I'd love to learn more about Capistrano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have spent good time over this and figured it out.

**Changes due to newly installed package:**

I used a package to export data to excel **Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel**. I had to to add service provider, alias and do `composer update`. The package created few config files in **app/config/packages/maatwebsite** folder.

**Other Changes:**

Apart from above mentioned things, when I did `composer update`, it updated **composer, symphony, monolog, phpoffice and autoload.php** inside **vendor** folder. It also created new folder called **maatwebsite** inside **vendor**. Apart from these, the views and controllers I changed myself to export data to excel.

So, I basically uploaded all the following to my website:

1. controller, views files I changed.
2. **composer.json** & **composer.lock** files.
3. Files & Folders inside **vender** (vendor/autoload.php, vendor/composer, vendor/symfony, vendor/phpoffice, vendor/maatwebsite)
4. Config files of newly installed package i.e. (**app/config/packages/maatwebsite**)
5. Finally my **app/config/app.php** file where I added service provider and alias

And the website is working perfectly fine. So there was no need to upload everything. :)

Hope this will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a proper deployment plan, having the `composer update` command run once the code has been deployed would fix all of that. Otherwise, you're going to have to upload everything that is new, and everything that has changed.

If the directory is empty, you're going to have to manually create it on the server. I would imagine that besides that directory, it'd be any published content, such as configs and what not, the package folder, composer.json and the composer autoload.

Comment: So I think the straight forward answer is, I'll have to upload everything once again to avoid issues.

Comment: That's definitely the simplest, but probably not the ideal.